# How to use a spread or map operator to apply this formula to an array of Uint16 pairs?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax, typedarray

I've been trying to better understand the spread and/or map operator, specifically how to apply math using it.

I have an array of two Uint16 number pairs like this:

```
let randomPairs = [
  [ 37096, 65104 ], [ 62271, 3432 ],  [ 1191, 43320 ],  [ 5388, 16819 ],
  [ 52224, 52222 ], [ 61913, 48798 ], [ 52950, 18227 ], [ 23232, 43931 ],
  [ 14995, 45924 ], [ 20609, 46597 ], [ 2392, 52582 ],  [ 7050, 51498 ],
  [ 34253, 11210 ], [ 43376, 41964 ], [ 63238, 34740 ], [ 63254, 56620 ]
]
```

I would like to use the spread or map operator to apply the following formula to each pair. The formula combines the pair into Uint32, then converts it to a float between 0-1.

`(((2**16) * u1) + u2) / ((2 ** 32)  - 1)`

Where `u1` represents the first item in a pair, and `u2` represents the second item in the pair.

I don't really know how to do it at all, but here is my code that takes the array and applies the formula using a for loop:

```
let i,j,temparray,chunk = 2, u1, u2
for (i=0,j=randomPairs.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {

    temparray = randomPairs.slice(i,i+chunk);
    u1 = temparray[0]
    u2 = temparray[1]
    let float = (((2**16) * u1) + u2) / ((2 ** 32)  - 1)
    
    console.log(float)
}
```

How can I use a spread or map operator to convert the `randomPairs` array into an array of the desired floats for each pair?

If `Float32Array()` could be used somehow, I'm all ears about that as well.

Comment: Couldn't you use the map method for this?

Comment: Yes, possibly, but I'm new to both. I have updated my question..

Comment: What you want is an array of float values corresponding to the result of plugging each pair into the formula right? If that's the case, I'll just write up the code as an answer using map.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply an operation on each element in an array, you can use the `map` method:

```js
let randomPairs = [
  [ 37096, 65104 ], [ 62271, 3432 ],  [ 1191, 43320 ],  [ 5388, 16819 ],
  [ 52224, 52222 ], [ 61913, 48798 ], [ 52950, 18227 ], [ 23232, 43931 ],
  [ 14995, 45924 ], [ 20609, 46597 ], [ 2392, 52582 ],  [ 7050, 51498 ],
  [ 34253, 11210 ], [ 43376, 41964 ], [ 63238, 34740 ], [ 63254, 56620 ]
]

let floats = randomPairs.map(p => {
    return (((2**16) * p[0]) + p[1]) / ((2 ** 32)  - 1);
});

console.log(floats);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `forEach` method if you just want to `console.log` the output and don't need an array of the resulting float values.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed.. Array manipulation isn't the easiest thing to grasp, so I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want :)

```
myPairs.map(pair => {
const [u1, u2] = pair;

return (((2**16) * u1) + u2) / ((2 ** 32)  - 1);
})
```

Comment: There's no need for the additional variable declaration you could as well destructure directly 

```
randomPairs.forEach(([u1, u2]) => {
  console.log(u1, u2)
});

```
Feel free to replace it with a map.

Comment: You're right. I made it that way so OP could understand the map function better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example showing how to use the spread operator *and* the map function:

```js
let randomPairs = [
  [ 37096, 65104 ], [ 62271, 3432 ],  [ 1191, 43320 ],  [ 5388, 16819 ],
  [ 52224, 52222 ], [ 61913, 48798 ], [ 52950, 18227 ], [ 23232, 43931 ],
  [ 14995, 45924 ], [ 20609, 46597 ], [ 2392, 52582 ],  [ 7050, 51498 ],
  [ 34253, 11210 ], [ 43376, 41964 ], [ 63238, 34740 ], [ 63254, 56620 ]
]

function foo(u1, u2) {
  console.log((((2**16) * u1) + u2) / ((2 ** 32)  - 1));
}

randomPairs.map(e => foo(...e));
```